# How to prove that if $det(A)=0$ then $Adj(A)$ is a null matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

> How to prove that if $det(A)=0$ then $Adj(A)$ is a null matrix?

Or is a matrix having columns with linear combinations of other columns.

Comment: Do you know that $A \text{Adj}(A) = \text{Adj}(A) A = \det(A) I$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}$

$det(A) = 0$

$adj (A) = \begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&1\\1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Your proposition is not true.

Now if you meant $(adj(A))A$ that would be different.